# multivariate seasonal time series in dlm in r

Tags: r, time-series, seasonality, bivariate, dlm

I am trying to build a dynamic linear model in R for my bivariate seasonal (monthly ) time series.
I found the following resources which help me to model bivariate cases but there is no seasonality component included(with my understanding ).

https://kevinkotze.github.io/ts-4-tut/ (Section 9)

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlm/dlm.pdf (page 17)

I am so please if you can help me to write the function with seasonality in dlm modeling.

Here is the code I used

```
library(dlm)
data(NelPlo)

# Build the function  

buildSu <- function(x) {

Vsd <- exp(x[1:2])

Vcorr <- tanh(x[3])

V <- Vsd %o% Vsd

V[1,2] <- V[2,1] <- V[1,2] * Vcorr

Wsd <- exp(x[4:5])

Wcorr <- tanh(x[6])

W <- Wsd %o% Wsd

W[1,2] <- W[2,1] <- W[1,2] * Wcorr

return(list(

m0 = rep(0,2),

C0 = 1e7 * diag(2),

FF = diag(2),

GG = diag(2),

V = V,

W = W))

}

# MLE parameter estimation
suMLE <- dlmMLE(NelPlo[,1:2], rep(0,6), buildSu); suMLE

buildSu(suMLE$par)[c("V","W")]

StructTS(NelPlo[,1], type="level") ## compare with W[1,1] and V[1,1]

StructTS(NelPlo[,2], type="level") ## compare with W[2,2] and V[2,2]

model.fit <- buildSu(suMLE$par)

model.filtered <- dlmFilter(NelPlo[,1:2], model.fit)

# forecasting 
y1 <- dlmForecast(model.filtered, nAhead=12,sampleNew=1)
```

I am so please if you can help me to write the function with seasonality in dlm modeling and any valuable R examples are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I gather that you have monthly data and a yearly seasonal. You need to include a block in your state equation to account for that: the dlm package helps you a lot, with functions dlmModSeas and dlmModTrig. Read the documentation (and also grab a copy of Giovanni Petris et al. book, *Dynamic Linear Models with R*, Springer Verlag, if you can).

Comment: Dear Sir Tusell,  Thank you so much for the guidance