# Building a Multivariate Dynamic Linear Model with Linear Trend and Seasonal Component

Tags: r, time-series, dlm

**Edit. I have made some progress myself, though I have not completely solved the issue. In short, I can fit what I think is a proper description of the model I want, and I can filter it, but I get an error when I try to smooth the series.**

I am trying to learn dynamic linear models, and at the same package learn the R `dlm` package. I am working on a bivariate model, with a linear trend and a seasonal component.

My problem seems to be similar to this one:: [multivariate seasonal time series in dlm in r](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/496180/multivariate-seasonal-time-series-in-dlm-in-r). However, the question was never fully answered, possibly because it was not asked in the most helpful way, so I am trying to do better.

I have data which is monthly earnings data for the public and private sector. Giving only the first 150 terms, we have:

```
    wagte_ts <- structure(c(308.290861533774, 316.530684266741, 331.743888321629, 
306.594956294593, 306.027101001177, 307.076661177941, 308.76716302708, 
306.690852083589, 307.433090292997, 306.986245592844, 309.995051318672, 
328.681605277824, 327.195905121307, 347.15245555423, 347.964828827004, 
324.364734228554, 320.217899800899, 325.110944448259, 323.34283388995, 
320.820032959977, 320.100668840809, 320.753753462972, 323.222759349371, 
337.27939496862, 338.12827654662, 355.677421696664, 355.901271268778, 
335.755672050744, 331.793925944446, 337.150458261689, 335.980595549076, 
330.87641788809, 330.188102027769, 330.151057982586, 331.207894731129, 
342.869144038744, 344.858279180566, 362.425420300597, 373.191779367584, 
342.650749718257, 340.168343874673, 343.818263492479, 344.136528156412, 
338.562073850514, 340.280968645349, 342.42188483732, 342.363805341863, 
355.138782969626, 375.103722845661, 375.331658230003, 386.980660179696, 
355.753018763449, 355.035915711533, 358.13737176751, 356.716793518281, 
353.617290393461, 353.730920593921, 355.982080718409, 355.646558476037, 
369.930772123952, 391.54084533459, 400.118529756671, 402.358447659466, 
369.692202668389, 366.485965661834, 372.847231937349, 372.766334714432, 
370.69354321552, 369.622582600347, 369.160362701586, 371.093215009388, 
385.13268581394, 404.041175750573, 427.310737680386, 429.170489909942, 
385.592382206257, 384.485370157067, 395.388917109155, 390.974271511583, 
385.036800592964, 384.397179042557, 386.046281843303, 387.851696831092, 
409.779975994435, 432.104085671683, 465.490307433595, 450.264212741427, 
402.301786627284, 402.777053922304, 412.998869184765, 410.940062015464, 
406.266667619616, 407.906970487913, 403.905424431376, 407.918831525952, 
422.633537720574, 448.303917729157, 487.531964828376, 473.372407741, 
422.413122266053, 420.933649120259, 427.575961055064, 422.62376680226, 
417.524029960729, 417.996459644235, 418.310993992427, 416.010490798953, 
432.718231833031, 435.567048807943, 450.157645552531, 464.519154738908, 
428.459004106226, 422.238155571426, 429.415493598734, 420.425787059163, 
416.178131930901, 418.319010374941, 416.316010216516, 417.215533674876, 
433.489759587151, 434.539657614529, 476.281528822169, 497.118716511785, 
426.17252550311, 426.71121993698, 429.654911227441, 426.965489927134, 
423.918168373215, 426.901222520576, 424.622995757888, 424.811046018574, 
437.303914420091, 455.218623802142, 479.218809566996, 506.617249449447, 
436.315667564017, 436.732418091388, 444.013691982126, 439.641775996537, 
432.611546202944, 434.283641362603, 433.779345309325, 434.172666621668, 
446.728809798405, 453.778336918204, 479.496720333331, 510.211708005973, 
448.43075128026, 445.113798880238, 451.672453648109, 310.0324461, 
313.4964538, 309.9609878, 312.5021811, 313.1695897, 315.8483268, 
314.8703445, 316.0584774, 315.2649533, 315.3843857, 317.5891229, 
318.3495274, 318.9433656, 320.9225182, 323.1526821, 330.7448764, 
331.2694976, 333.381977, 335.105811, 337.737461, 334.8955832, 
334.4042485, 332.9823066, 335.5708839, 333.9666149, 334.3330305, 
335.2132755, 342.2402084, 343.1987542, 345.2481832, 346.9219502, 
343.8244583, 345.5552652, 351.4121678, 354.0166457, 352.9979363, 
347.7197493, 348.6557524, 350.1811226, 357.0886325, 356.6568806, 
361.7754789, 363.6351258, 369.2773349, 365.2846702, 363.627172, 
365.683382, 368.9107804, 363.0978998, 364.9628407, 365.7322735, 
373.3295851, 373.9703394, 380.1124834, 376.6738597, 382.4596607, 
381.3616279, 380.6622901, 381.540223, 385.6347144, 381.9888352, 
381.4113695, 385.7814637, 393.7371213, 403.8461312, 397.9705898, 
396.3573552, 398.6920221, 398.7026547, 399.2584819, 400.5386078, 
407.3677186, 400.0215383, 405.2682142, 401.3654417, 405.9010092, 
417.9745845, 411.3067436, 411.7957221, 410.5059509, 409.549643, 
410.7160315, 412.7244427, 421.3791563, 414.6155914, 414.4085346, 
415.034459, 420.8151987, 435.4162418, 424.6476909, 421.355185, 
423.8080039, 422.5625015, 422.1561807, 433.0509514, 439.5683304, 
426.6424095, 429.0802868, 430.3101237, 437.1621518, 448.2273868, 
436.5181258, 440.4521064, 443.0132659, 438.7809187, 437.4060042, 
447.5858802, 451.6517803, 441.092287355659, 445.212950533952, 
440.617879458936, 449.197487535961, 461.103177567988, 453.223931145868, 
454.316398566751, 453.887209357487, 455.395346057223, 457.209344211914, 
457.790309779321, 461.976006658894, 457.286032796149, 459.401743246316, 
464.46472171561, 463.441160044312, 464.962795394293, 491.055240617451, 
464.766801420739, 465.157732937526, 468.36069292613, 467.159873365256, 
470.330390434723, 472.4548499908, 469.548558835005, 471.186670179895, 
483.886768275157, 475.180338893745, 474.730219639069, 508.50626503279, 
481.206031980456, 475.614874704173, 477.684053949812, 476.250589393522, 
479.280790141237, 479.186258907227, 473.231520471005, 476.785161163371, 
487.127050909639, 481.081223166077, 482.54581724827, 513.486709585745
), dim = c(150L, 2L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("Private Sector", 
"Public Sector")))
```

Now, with the help of this [tutorial](https://gradientdescending.com/state-space-models-for-time-series-analysis-and-the-dlm-package/) I found it easy to build and run a univariate model.

```
##### Univariate State Space Model

# forecasting using state sapce models
model.build <- function(p) {
    return(
      dlmModPoly(2, dV=p[1], dW=p[2:3]) +
      dlmModSeas(12, dV=p[4])
    )
}


model.mle <- dlmMLE(wage_ts[,1], parm=c(0.1, 0, 1, 1), build=model.build)
if(model.mle$convergence==0) print("converged") else print("did not converge")
```

The real problem I want to solve is how to build a bivariate model. I have found a useful [resource](https://kevinkotze.github.io/ts-4-tut/), and working from that I think that the code for the model I want is:

```
# Define the model building function with the provided FF and GG structure
build1 <- function(par) {
    m <- dlmModPoly(2) + dlmModSeas(12)
    
    # Adjust the dimensions of FF and GG to match the structure you provided
    FF <- matrix(c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE)
    GG <- diag(12)
    
    m$FF <- FF
    m$GG <- GG
    
    W1 <- diag(1e-07, nr = 12)
    W2 <- diag(exp(par[1:2]))
    W2[1, 2] <- W2[2, 1] <- tanh(par[3]) * prod(exp(0.5 * par[1:2]))
    W <- bdiag(W1, W2)
    m$W <- W
    
    V <- diag(exp(par[4:5]))
    V[1, 2] <- V[2, 1] <- tanh(par[6]) * prod(exp(0.5 * par[4:5]))
    m$V <- V
    
    m$m0 <- rep(0, 14)  # Adjust to match the dimensionality of FF
    m$C0 <- diag(14) * 1e+07  # Adjust to match the dimensionality of FF
    
    return(m)
```

And to run the model you can use the following code:

```
 # Define plausible alternative starting parameters
initial_params_private <- c(0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
initial_params_public <- c(0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)

# Estimate the model parameters using MLE for each series
mle_results <- vector("list", 2)

for (i in 1:2) {
    if (i == 1) {
        mle_results[[i]] <- try(dlmMLE(wage_ts[, i], parm = initial_params_private, build = build1))
    } else {
        mle_results[[i]] <- try(dlmMLE(wage_ts[, i], parm = initial_params_public, build = build1))
    }
}

# Check convergence and display results
for (i in 1:2) {
    if (class(mle_results[[i]]) == "try-error") {
        cat("MLE estimation for series", i, "did not converge.\n")
    } else {
        cat("MLE estimation for series", i, "converged.\n")
        print(mle_results[[i]])
    }
}
```

This seems to work and gives the following results.

```
$par
[1] 0.50000000 0.50000000 0.10000000 0.09999999 0.10000000 0.10000000

$value
[1] 150923.2

$counts
function gradient 
      26       26 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"

MLE estimation for series 2 converged.
$par
[1] 0.5 0.5 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1

$value
[1] 125629

$counts
function gradient 
      20       20 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```

I can get filtered estimates using the following code.

```
# Create a list to store filtered models for each series
filtered_models <- vector("list", 2)

# Filter the fitted models for each series
for (i in 1:2) {
    if (!is.null(mle_results[[i]])) {
        # Construct the fitted model using the estimated parameters
        fitted_model <- build1(mle_results[[i]]$par)
        
        # Filter the model using the observed data
        filtered_models[[i]] <- dlmFilter(wage_ts[, i], fitted_model)
    }
}

###Commented out as extremely verbose

# Display filtered models and results
#for (i in 1:2) {
#    if (!is.null(filtered_models[[i]])) {
#        cat("Filtered model for series", i, ":\n")
#        print(filtered_models[[i]])
#    }
#}
```

The problem arises when I try to smooth the series.

```
# Create a list to store smoothed models for each series
smoothed_models <- vector("list", 2)

# Smoothed the fitted models for each series
for (i in 1:2) {
    if (!is.null(mle_results[[i]])) {
        # Construct the fitted model using the estimated parameters
        fitted_model <- build1(mle_results[[i]]$par)
        
        # Smooth the model
        smoothed_models[[i]] <- dlmSmooth(wage_ts[, i], fitted_model)
    }
}
```

This gives the following error.

```
Error in dlmSmooth.dlmFiltered(dlmFilter(y, mod, ...), ...) : 
  error code 13 from Lapack routine dgesdd
```

This is where I get stuck. Any help greatly appreciated.